# Cannot call function and send write-Transaction from geth-console

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, truffle, console

I have a contract which has this function:

```
function registerSensor(bytes32 name, bytes32 unit, bytes32 location) returns (bool success)
{
    sensors[msg.sender].exists = true;
    sensors[msg.sender].name = name;
    sensors[msg.sender].unit = unit;
    sensors[msg.sender].location = location;
    addresses.push(msg.sender);
    return true;
}
```

If I call this function in the truffle-console with this command:

```
Svd.then(function(instance) {return instance.registerSensor("Miner", "MH/s", "Desk"); })
```

then everything works fine, the sensor gets added to the addresses-array.

If I try to do the same in the geth-console then nothing happens, the sensor doesn't get added to the addresses-array. I can see the transaction is send and I also get a transaction id.

```
var svd = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"addr","type":"address"}],"name":"getSensorData","outputs":[{"name":"data","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getSensorAddresses","outputs":[{"name":"addr","type":"address[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"unit","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"location","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"registerSensor","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"addr","type":"address"}],"name":"getSensorMetaData","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"unit","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"location","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"constructor"}]).at('0x27517492524152c925061648b15d78d451bbd04b')

svd.registerSensor("Node 1", "C", "Desk", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}, function(err, result) {
   console.log(err);
   console.log(result);
})
```

Here is the output of the console:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that I didn't defined a gas-limit, so after adding the max amount of gas it is finally working:

```
svd.registerSensor("Node 1", "C", "Desk", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:3000000})
```

:), seems like truffle adds the gas-limit automatically